# VST Plugins similar to Dblue Glitch?

Tags: effects, vst

I've had a lot of fun with dblue glitch vst. I was wondering if there are similar vst plugins that achieve the same clean cutting and manipulating that it does?

Comment: Added Community Wiki since this is a list-of-useful-tools question. As usual in CW, one tool per answer please, so they can be up- and down-voted individually.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that iZotope Stutter Edit is a great plugin, and I haven't used Artillery from Sugar Bytes, I think the following is more similar to dBlue Glitch than the previous mentioned:

[Effectrix](http://www.sugar-bytes.com/content/products/Effectrix/index.php?lang=en) by Sugar Bytes.

Answer (score 2):

[iZotope Stutter Edit](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/stutteredit/) is a similar glitch-effect plugin. It focuses on pre-defined tempo-synced sampling and effect movements that are triggered by MIDI notes, called 'gestures.' It is somewhat more focused on live performance than studio work, although it is useful for both.

Notably, gesture length is not an absolute amount of time - after triggering a gesture, the gesture goes *until the next specified time interval*. So if the "length" of the gesture is one bar, the gesture will go from the time it's triggered until the end of the next bar.

Answer (score 2):

there is [Artillery](http://www.sugar-bytes.com/content/products/Artillery2/index.php?lang=en) from Sugar Bytes. The difference is that effects are triggered with MIDI notes while in Glitch they are sequenced in the Plug itself.

Comment: Second this....You can trigger from Artillery UI by right clicking on a key...That latches it.